# Redirect all urls except one in Apache 000-default.conf

Tags: apache2, http-redirect

I have a requirement to keep one URL as HTTP and rest all URLs are https.
My currency 000-default.conf configs are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    Redirect permanent / **https**://www.abc.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This redirects all the URLs to https.
Now I have a URL on this site as **http**://www.abc.com/blog
I don't want it to get redirected to https. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current recipe is a bit confused. The RewriteCond doesn't block the Redirect that comes after it, it only affects a RewriteRule. But you will never see a HTTPS request on a port 80 vhost.

You can switch your redirect to actually use mod_rewrite and add the exception. The conditions are AND'ed by default:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog$
RewriteRule ^(/.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: example.com used instead of your URL -- answers can't contain that URL apparently but questions can!